# Sorting Month names chronologically in the tidyverse

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, tidyverse

So I have read a number of methods to sort Months by their names either in base R or via the tidyverse methodology, but all require user defined functions and or some pretty verbose language.

Here is an example:
[Sorting month chronologicaly with arrange() from dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493897/sorting-month-chronologicaly-with-arrange-from-dplyr)

This is a basic need in almost any analysis that involves dates or times. Surly there has to be a function such as arrange() with a "calendar" (and maybe descd-calendar) argument. Or Am I missing something?

Comment: I fail to see how the linked question is really that verbose. It's one line to convert to a properly ordered factor and then `arrange`. Yes, you can do it a bit shorter as shown below, but having a `factor` means the order will persist when plotting/tabling etc.

Comment: thelatemail, I agree that the example is not too verbose, its just that this is such a common practice as I said, I'm just surprised that there is not a better implemented standard argument to arrange() or other similar functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe arrange based on their positions in `month.name`, which can be found with `match(months, month.name)`?

```
df <- data.frame(months = sample(month.name, 5))
df
#     months
#1 September
#2      July
#3  December
#4  February
#5   January

df %>% arrange(match(months, month.name))
#     months
#1   January
#2  February
#3      July
#4 September
#5  December
```

Comment: PSidom, I think that this is as simple a method that I have seen. I will have to give this a try in my code on Monday; thanks.

Comment: So tried this out this morning with success, thanks again Psidom. Looks like this is exactly what I was saying is needed for month sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert them to `Date`s and then sort them.

```
library(anydate); library(dplyr);
c('January', 'February', 'December', 'June') %>% anydate %>% sort
```

If you want to keep them as strings you could use Psidom's method or do

```
c('January', 'February', 'December', 'June') %>% (function(x) x[x %>% anydate %>% order])
```

Comment: library name is anytime not anydate